# Creating array using another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having an array in which i have added 3 data in different index,  as below

```
  var a=[];
   a[1]=4;
   a[3]=7;
   a[4]=8;
```

now my array will look like this

```
 a=[undefined, 4, undefined, 7, 8, undefined]
```

i want to take the value alone from the array and need to add in another array. is there any simplest way, that i can make use of it. Till now i am taking the value using "for" loop, it is ok when i have small number of data. here i need only 3 values, but the loop execute for 6 time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: On a side note - sparse arrays are _extremely_ slow compared to whole arrays. Array 'holes' cause JS engines to vastly degrade in performance and causes very bad "de-optimizes". Full arrays on the other hand are almost as fast as C arrays. If you explain the use case (why you got those holes in the array) we can probably give you a much better guided answer. I'm yet to see a justified use case for them (I might be surprised today :)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function is what you are after.

```
var newArray = a.filter(function(item) {
  return item !== undefined;
});
```

Comment: Note, checking `typeof` against undefined is not required when you have an undefined, but declared variable. The use of `typeof var !== 'undefined'` is for when the identifier doesn't exist. Function arguments are automatically declared and assigned 'undefined' so you can do `item !== undefined`

Answer (score 4):

Most array methods skip over "holes" anyway.

If you don't explicitly want to filter them out, just call an array method on them:

```
var arr = a.filter(function(){return true});
```

Or shorthand:

```
[,4,,7,8].filter(function(){ return true}); // [4, 7, 8]
```

Comment: You could also do `a.filter(isFinite)` if it's just numbers.

Comment: @elclanrs I considered it (or `map(Number)`) to be honest :) The only issue I saw with that is array values that are not numbers, or array values that are declared but set to undefined. For example with holes -  `[undefined]` should go to `[undefined]` while `[,,]` should go to `[]`

Comment: Yes I guess it has a quite specific use. Btw, `.filter(Number)` will filter out zeroes while `isFinite` won't.

Answer (score 0):

**The raw array:**

```
var originalArr = [];
a[1] = 4;
a[3] = 7;
a[4] = 8;
```

**The filter logic:**

```
function filterUndefined(originalArr){
    var valuesArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < originalArr.length; i++){
        if(originalArr[i] !== undefined){
          valuesArray.push(a[i]);
        }
        return valuesArray;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
[4,7,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is, whenever you set an index in an array whereas the other previous indexes are not there, your array add them with undefined values. If you have a huge amount of data in this array it is not a good practice.

You can use filter to actually filter the undefined values but the point is, when the array has a huge amount of data, what you do is creating 2 array which the first array has lots of indexes with undefined values, which is not a good practice. I believe it is more of a `HashMap` instead of `Array`.

if I where you I would use javascript object instead, and to loop through it like an array, you can do:

```
var a={};
a[1]=4;
a[3]=7;
a[4]=8;
var keys = Object.keys(a);
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    var value = a[keys[i]];
    //do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a 'key/value' object instead of an array.

```
> var a={}; 
> a[1]=4; 
> a[3]=7; 
> a[4]=8;
```

Note that the difference is the way you declare 'a': a={} rather than a=[].